# Placing methods in foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, bing-maps

not sure if the title is really correct, but this is the issue...

I have a foreach loop populating a pushpin collection. I need to do some 'work' on one of the XML elements (Latitude). the 'work' is commented out. The problem is I cant see where to put these tasks/variables anywhere. wherever I place it I get a varity of errors. I can go into more detail of that if needed, but wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Its preey self explanitory below what im trying to do but let me know if you need more explanation. Any suggestions welcome.

```
  public void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 
        var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
        if (document.Root == null)
            return;
         var events = from ev in document.Descendants("item")

                      .Where(ev => ev.Element("category") != null)

                     select new 
                     {

                         Title = (ev.Element("title").Value),
                         Description = (ev.Element("description").Value),
                         Category = (ev.Element("category").Value),
                         Latitude = (ev.Element("link").Value),

                      };


         ObservableCollection<Eng> pushPinCollection = new ObservableCollection<Eng>();

        foreach (var ev in events)
         {

             Eng PushPin = new Eng
               (ev.Title, ev.Description, ev.Category)

           // Lat1 = (ev.Latitude),
            //  var items = Lat1.Split('?')[1].Split('&').Select(i => i.Split  ('=')).ToDictionary(o => o[0], o => o[1]); 
            //  var lon = items["lon"]; 
            //  var lat = items["lat"];
            //  var lat1 = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
            //  var lon1 = Convert.ToDouble(lon);
             {

        //Location value below is System.Device.location.Geocoordinate Eng Location
                  Location = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lon1),
                  Title = ev.Title,
                  Description = ev.Description,
                  Category = ev.Category

             };
            pushPinCollection.Add(PushPin);
         }
         pushPins = pushPinCollection;
         mapItems.ItemsSource = PushPins;

       }
```

Comment: What "varity of errors" are you seeing?

Comment: Worked this out actually, basically i'd tried every combination of positions and , and ; apart from the one that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking...you should declare variables in the "narrowest" scope possible.  However, if you'll be accessing the variables outside of the For Loop, you'll need to declare them outside the For Loop.  Probably just above the "foreach (var ev in events)" line should be Ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert any code between the end of the call to the Constructor, and the initializer. There are several ways to address this:

```
Eng pushPin = new Eng(...);  // note the semicolon

// calculations to get lat1 and lon1

pushPin.Location = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lon1); // Location must have a public Set
```

or

```
// calculations for lat1 and lon 1

Eng PushPin = new Eng(ev.Title, ev.Description, ev.Category)
                  {
                      Location = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lon1);
                  }
```

or if you have a constructor that takes the GeoCoordinate:

```
 Eng PushPin = new Eng(ev.Title, ev.Description, ev.Category, new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lon1));
```